# BufferedReader throws java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

I was reading a file and putting the contents into a BlockingQueue().

To check whether the method that takes the strings from that BlockingQueue() waits properly, I used `Thread.sleep(10)`. But it threw a 'Stream closed' error.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
    Thread.sleep(10);
    queue.put(line);
}
```

After few reads, I got:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:292)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
```

What is the mistake I'm doing here? Is there any specific timeout for `BufferedReader`?

Edit: The remiaing part is, I'm reading that queue parallely from another method.

Comment: The `ensureOpen` method checks whether the underlying reader is `null` throwing the mentioned exception if yes. And that can only happen, if you call `close` on your buffered reader. So there must be some more code that produces your problem. The shown code snippet cannot have such an outcome.

Comment: please provide a minimal running example (where does queue come from and what is your input file looking like). I tried to reproduce but without success.

Comment: @shi:The above code is in a method and I'm reading the queue from another method simultaneously. Actually, I used this sleep to check whether the second method waits till the queue gets some input from the above method.

Comment: @Harbinger Adding a `sleep()` doesn't accomplish that, or anything else useful. Neither does the second thread. Just have the code that processes the data read the file directly. You don't need two threads, or a queue, for that.

Comment: The question is why would you want to process that string in another thread and not in your loop?

Comment: I wanted to read the large input file in a single thread and used another thread to read the contents and apply some logics and send it to another thread. I used 2 threads, so as to reduce the time to read from file. Is this not a proper way?

Comment: No it isn't. It's just a waste of time. You can't magically gain any time this way. All you've accomplished is some non-working code. Get rid of the queue and the two threads and do it the easy way.

Comment: There is in fact time to be gained with this approach, but only in certain scenarios: if you have occasional long waits until the next line is available, with your approach you wouldn't be blocked on the processing side. However, the processing time should be substantial (compared to average I/O latency for single line) for this effect to manifest.

Comment: @MarkoTopolink He is reading from a file.

Comment: @EJP That doesn't make a lot of difference---file reads are prone to the same latency issues on a busy system. Not to even mention network-based filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

> But it threw a 'Stream closed' error.

It threw this error because you had already closed the stream, possibly in some other thread.

NB the `sleep()` in your code is pointless.

Comment: Actually, I used this sleep to check whether the second method waits till the queue gets some input from the above method

Comment: @Harbinger I don't know why you're using a queue or another thread at all, but if it's a `BlockingQueue` that behaviour is guaranteed by the specification, and if it isn't it should be. Adding `sleep()`s to your code doesn't help one way or the other.